# Python type hints. Как уточнить тип объекта?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class AbstractObject(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass


class BObject(AbstractObject):
    pass


class CObject(AbstractObject):
    pass


class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def restore_object(self) -> "AbstractObject":
        a = self.create_object()
        # другие действия
        return a

    @abstractmethod
    def create_object(self) -> "AbstractObject":
        pass


class B(A):

    def create_object(self):
        return BObject()


class C(A):

    def create_object(self):
        return CObject()


b_manager = B()
c_manager = C()

one_object: "BObject" = b_manager.restore_object()  # здесь ошибка типа
two_object: "CObject" = c_manager.restore_object()  # Expected type 'BObject', got 'AbstractObject' instead
```

При вызове метода "restore_object" не получается указать нужный тип. В некоторых других языках можно уточнить возвращаемый тип, от абстрактного, примерно тем синтаксисом, который я указал. А как решить эту задачу в Питоне?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#abstract-base-classes

Comment: @Jack_oS, и на что там внимание обратить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать класс `A` [дженериком](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) (если вы используете Python 3.5 или новее):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=AbstractObject)


class A(Generic[T]):
    def restore_object(self) -> T:
        a = self.create_object()
        # другие действия
        return a

    @abstractmethod
    def create_object(self) -> T:
        pass


class B(A[BObject]):

    def create_object(self):
        return BObject()


class C(A[CObject]):

    def create_object(self):
        return CObject()


b_manager = B()
c_manager = C()

one_object: "BObject" = b_manager.restore_object()
two_object: "CObject" = c_manager.restore_object()
```

Comment: Тогда и аннотации типов возле `one_object` и `two_object` не требуются

Comment: @andreymal, ну тут как посмотреть, может там глядя на код без IDE не очевидно какой тип возвращается. Вот такое `b_manager: B = B()` (почти java style) было бы точно излишне, а так просто дополнительная подсказка для себя (или кто этот код будет читать).

Comment: @insolor, решение работает. Нужно подтянуть генерики. Спасибо.

Comment: `T = TypeVar('T', bound=AbstractObject)`

Comment: @hoefling, да, спасибо, так будет правильнее.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
class AbstractObject(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass


class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def restore_object(self) -> AbstractObject:
        a = self.create_object()
        # другие действия
        return a
```

или так, если ожидается **неизвестный заранее** тип:

```
from typing import Any

class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def restore_object(self) -> Any:
        a = self.create_object()
        # другие действия
        return a
```

Comment: Тип то известный, но нужна возможность уточнить потомка абстрактного класса. Можно, пожалуй, решить через `Union[BObject,CObject]`, но тогда получается, что родитель должен знать о наследниках, что не очень правильно.